# Windows service stopped without any errors

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I created a windows service to host some WCF services,
but when I start it, it stop with a message:
[image]

I checked windows log viewer and there isn't any errors

and I tested everything on a console application before and it's working.

My code is:

```
ServiceHost host1;
ServiceHost host2;
ServiceHost host3;

public ServicesHost()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (host1 != null)            
        host1.Close();
    if (host2 != null)
        host2.Close();
    if (host3 != null)
        host3.Close();            
    host1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
    host1.Open();    
    host2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service2));
    host2.Open();    
    host3 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service3));
    host3.Open();                       
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    host1.Close();
    host1 = null;
    host2.Close();
    host2 = null;
    host3.Close();
    host3 = null;
}
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"
           name="Service2">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="IService2">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Service2" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"
           name="Service3">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="IService3">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Service3" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>

</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Edit:
I have installer:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ServiceInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller service;

    public ServiceInstaller()
    {            
        process = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.NetworkService;
        service = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "WCFHostService";
        service.DisplayName = "WCFHostService";
        service.Description = "WCF Service Hosted";
        service.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will depending what you're doing when you call host.Open().  Also i believe that the service won't log anything unless you explicitly state it has to.

Comment: Which user account is used to run the NT Serice? When runnning as console you run under the credentials that started the console (usually the developer logged in with high security privileges). When running as NTService, it's a assign windows account. Could it have something to do with the privileges the account has?
I Also seem to be missing "Service1" in the configuration section.
Which version of the .Net framework are you using? (NTServices configuration loading has changed)

Comment: .net 4, and I don't know which account is used to run services, but I just tried a simple code now and the same happened, just simple text writing didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a console/desktop application runs but not as service, it's mostly a userright problem. This applies on like, using COM/DCOM or the use of files, because the current path for a service is the windows\system32.

Try to wrap the OnStart with try/catch and write the exception to the EventLog -> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024

---

Did you create any installers for the service?
*How to: Add Installers to Your Service Application* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf.aspx

Comment: I did so, and I tried also a text file to write errors, both of them didn't report any errors.

Comment: Did you create any installers for the service? I think you could missed that one, because when you wrap it in try/catch it shouldn't be stopping. For more info about installers: _How to: Add Installers to Your Service Application_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf.aspx

Comment: Additionally now I tried just a simple code to write a text file and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Did you use something like _string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine( System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "error.log");_ because default it will tries to write to the system32 directory. (which is not allowed)

Comment: no I thought that would happen so I specified an absolute path.

Comment: I non error (any line) is logged, then the installer isn't working right. U could try re-installing the service. Else I advise to create a clean empty windows service step-by-step with a tutorial a see where is wen't wrong.

Comment: thanks a lot, apparently my service installer was faulty and following the steps fixed the problem.

Comment: Good to hear, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not logging at all. A window service should have a good logging system to survive in the production/mainteinance phase. Add a loggin system, put a try catch in the start, catch and log the exception in a file, this will hel you for the problem you are facing now, but help every day in your project lifetime.